# Redirect in React Router based on a component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to redirect users based on their logged in state. In the React Router examples, they use `onEnter`. However, the function for `onEnter` does not have access to the components' states. In my case, the user's logged in status is stored in the root component. How can I redirect the user based on the root component's state?

For example, my code looks something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="login" component={PageLogin}/>
            <Route component={PageAuth}>
                <IndexRoute component={PageHome}/>
                ...
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('react'));
```

In App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = new (Immutable.Record({...}));
    }
    ...
};
```

In PageAuth:

```
class PageAuth extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();

        if (!props.state.user.id) {
            ReactRouter.browserHistory.push('/login');
        }
    }
    ...
};
```

This redirects as expected, but I'm getting `Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render'). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`. I'm assuming I shouldn't be redirecting inside the constructor. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It may not be the redirect that is causing the warning but something in your render method that tries to perform a setState. A better way of redirecting would be to check for `props.state.user.id` in the componentDidMount or componentWillReceiveProps methods.

Comment: I tried changing my render method to just return a `<div/>`, but the error still occurs. Do you know if componentDidMount or componentWillReceiveProps is preferred?

Comment: Yup, it's more preferred as the you can easily check props that are existing or will be receiving by comparing this.props and nextProps in componentWillReceiveProps. I usually check in both methods just to be sure though, if there can be a state where user does not have to be authenticated in that component.

Comment: For more advanced usage of authentication, you can look here https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/04/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/